# Getting - ERROR Failed to send 'Newsletter Sign Up Confirmation' to 'Alias PII removed'

Tags: exm

I have installed `Sitecore 9 Update 1`. I have created scenario where I have created form in Sitecore Forms and triggering Goal during form submit. In Marketing Automation I have created campaign where I hooked to this goal in Start step as rule. In next steps I am adding contact to custom contact list and send automated email campaign. Unfortunately both of these steps are not working. Contact is not added to Contact list and also email is not send out with this error message:

> ManagedPoolThread #5 16:26:39 INFO  Registered email:
>   something@outlook.com ManagedPoolThread #4 16:26:39 INFO  Dispatch
>   Message (Newsletter Sign Up Confirmation): Started   Message Id:
>   {B6B6C836-54CA-4FA3-B145-0183A8A31544}   Message Path:
>   /sitecore/content/Email/Messages/2018/02/02T120314/Newsletter Sign Up
>   Confirmation   Included Recipient Lists:    Excluded Recipient Lists:
>
> MessageTaskRunner worker thread 12 16:26:39 ERROR Failed to send
>   'Newsletter Sign Up Confirmation' to 'Alias PII removed'.
>   MessageTaskRunner worker thread 12 16:26:39 ERROR Message sending
>   error: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.    at
>   Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Cm.Dispatch.DispatchTask.OnSendToNextRecipient()
>   MessageTaskRunner worker thread 11 16:26:39 ERROR Failed to send
>   'Newsletter Sign Up Confirmation' to 'Alias PII removed'.
>   MessageTaskRunner worker thread 11 16:26:39 ERROR Message sending
>   error: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.    at
>   Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Cm.Dispatch.DispatchTask.OnSendToNextRecipient()
>   MessageTaskRunner worker thread 13 16:26:39 ERROR Failed to send
>   'Newsletter Sign Up Confirmation' to 'Alias PII removed'.
>   MessageTaskRunner worker thread 15 16:26:39 ERROR Failed to send
>   'Newsletter Sign Up Confirmation' to 'Alias PII removed'.
>   MessageTaskRunner worker thread 13 16:26:39 ERROR Message sending
>   error: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.    at
>   Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Cm.Dispatch.DispatchTask.OnSendToNextRecipient()
>   MessageTaskRunner worker thread 15 16:26:39 ERROR Message sending
>   error: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.    at
>   Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Cm.Dispatch.DispatchTask.OnSendToNextRecipient()
>   ManagedPoolThread #4 16:26:41 INFO  Time to send: 2129 ms
>   ManagedPoolThread #4 16:26:41 INFO   ManagedPoolThread #4 16:26:41
>   INFO   ManagedPoolThread #4 16:26:41 INFO  Dispatch Message
>   (Newsletter Sign Up Confirmation): Finished   Result:          ABORTED
>   Message Id:      {B6B6C836-54CA-4FA3-B145-0183A8A31544}   Message
>   Path:    /sitecore/content/Email/Messages/2018/02/02T120314/Newsletter
>   Sign Up Confirmation   Recipients Processed:    0   Message Total Sent
>   Recipients:    0   Message Total Failed Recipients:  0   Message Total
>   Skipped Recipients (Enable log DEBUG level to see why):  0   Included
>   Recipient Lists:    Excluded Recipient Lists:

Has anybody encountered this issue?

Comment: Did you configure the Manager Root?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the custom contact list that you're using?  Does the contact show up on the list?  Does the contact have the appropriate information it needs to send an email? Are you setting an email address to the preferred smtp address on the Emails facet?  Can you provide the code you're using to save the contact details?

Comment: @JacobNielsen - Manager Root is configured correctly. Test connection button works and I can send emails through another email campaign without any problems

Comment: Solution was to create Submit Action that is creating contact during submitting form. I have followed [this Sitecore doc article](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/digital_marketing/sitecore_forms/setting_up_and_configuring/walkthrough_creating_a_custom_submit_action_that_updates_contact_details)! @PeteNavarra - Saving contact details is done by this custom action now; No errors now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution was to create custom submit action for Sitecore Forms 9 that is saving first name, last name and email address for contact. Error message is gone. I have created custom submit action based on [this Sitecore doc article](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/digital_marketing/sitecore_forms/setting_up_and_configuring/walkthrough_creating_a_custom_submit_action_that_updates_contact_details)!

Comment: I know it's your own answer, but please do feel free to mark it as the accepted answer :-)

Comment: I would like to @SteveMcGill but I need to wait couple of hours...

Answer (score 1):

I had faced the same issue, I have crated custom contact list for news latter with email id only. The list is visible to List Manager under contact lists category but without any contact. Please check whether you are able to see the contacts under your custom contact list.

I identified that the First Name and Last Name field is compulsory parameter to create any contact under the contact list. so try with adding First Name and Last Name along with Email Id.

Comment: I ended up with solution below which worked well

Comment: Cool, ultimately issue should be resolved :)

Answer (score 0):

\App_Config\Sitecore\EmailExperience\Sitecore.EDS.Providers.CustomSmtp*

AuthenticationMethod the Sitecore docs define that it can be either NONE, LOGIN, PLAIN, CRAM-MD5 or NTLM

I tried – LOGIN – worked!